# Angular: Data becomes undefined when used in angular component template but exists in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public blogposts: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   ngOnInit() {

       this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/demo/all").
      subscribe(function(data){
        this.blogposts=data;
        console.log(this.blogposts[0]);

      })

   }
}
```

`Console.log(this.blogposts[0])` does log the first object in the array but when used it inside  the component template it becomes undefined

and component's template is as follows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <app-blog-post *ngIf="blogposts[0]" [title]="blogposts[0].title"></app-blog-post>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">456</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">123</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">456</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I use  `<app-blog-post *ngIf="blogposts[0]" >`  nothing gets displayed at all and if I instead use `<app-blog-post *ngIf="blogposts" >` empty `<app-blog-post>` gets displayed
If I remove `*ngIf` completely then default value I assigned to title ie 'abc' gets displayed.

Child component is

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post',
  templateUrl: './blog-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-post.component.css']
})
export class BlogPostComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  @Input() title:String="abc";
}
```

and its template is

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

Even though blogposts contain an array of blogbost objects, `blogposts[0]` is `undefined` in the template and the `blogpost` exists but cannot access its content objects from the template? Why this happens?

Comment: Why don't you directly assign the value `this.blogposts=data[0];` and check it works or not.

Comment: try to pass the condition to ngIf as follow, `*ngIF="blogposts.length === 1"`. Since the blogPost is initiallized with zero objects, your ngIf condition is most likely to throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the title as Input `@Input() title:String="abc";` you should pass the entire object as input. for example `@input() blogpost: Blogpost = {}` 
then in your `HTML` you should pass the blogpost :    `<app-blog-post [blogpost]="blogposts[0]"></app-blog-post>`. 

then display the title in blogpost component.

This will actually check for changes in Angular `changeDetection` . because you only pass a propery of an object, and not the entire object, then the change detection does not consider the changes has real changes.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with which expression is being evaluated first. Basically `ngIf` runs when your array is still empty and then change detection doesn't pick it up. I recommend wrapping your component with a `div` and use `ngIf` on that.

Instead of:

```html
<app-blog-post *ngIf="blogposts[0]" [title]="blogposts[0].title"></app-blog-post>
```

Use:

```html
<div *ngIf="blogposts[0]">
    <app-blog-post [title]="blogposts[0].title"></app-blog-post>
</div>
```

You can make the expression even more explicit (in case `blogposts[0]` is falsy):

```html
<div *ngIf="blogposts.length > 0 && blogposts[0].title != null">
    <app-blog-post [title]="blogposts[0].title"></app-blog-post>
</div>
```

This will guarantee the `ngIf` is evaluated before the `app-blog-post` component is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your title binding might throw an error. Because you are trying to access blogposts[0].title which is not yet available. Initially '**blogposts[0].title**' is equivalent to **'undefined.title'**. You can fix this by changing the ngIf condition as follows,

```
<app-blog-post *ngIf="blogposts && blogposts.length === 1" [title]="blogposts[0].title"></app-blog-post>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function instead of function statement.

Every new function created by function statement, defined its own this value based on how the function was called. so using arrow function will refer to current object

**Try this**

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/demo/all").
       subscribe((data) =>{
        this.blogposts=data;
        console.log(this.blogposts[0]);
      })
   }
```